# Is it true that in Javascript the order of the for in loops is determined by the priority field in the objects?

Tags: javascript

Is it true that in Javascript the order of the `for in` loops is determined by the `priority` field in the objects?

```
var objs={
    foo:{priority:0,name:"foo"},
    bar:{priority:1,name:"bar"},
}
for(key in objs){
    console.log(objs[key].name)
}
```

First I see bar, then foo.

So is it true?

Comment: No, it's not. The [order produced by `for..in`](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) is not standard, it can be what ever.

Comment: I see foo and then bar

Comment: I would like to know how you came to that "conclusion" at all.

Comment: Property order is undefined and can change at any time. Use an array if order is important to you.

Comment: @nietonfir, in angular you can have multiole controllers on a node. I was wondering what determines the order in which these controllers are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, usually the loop over the properties of an object in the order in which they were defined, however it's not a standard.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was confused, because if you print the object which is a collection of key:value's, with let's say keys "foo" and "bar", the "bar" item is shown first, because that's how the print function apperently works, so it doesn't show the order in which these two items are inserted.